# How to remove spaces from string with while do operator? Pascal

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I have text and I need to remove spaces from beginning of text and from end of text. And I can do it only with while do operator. How can I do that? Here's program code

```
     program RandomTeksts;
     uses crt;
     var
     t:String;
     l, x, y:Integer;

    const tmin=1; tmax=30;
    label
    Start,
    end;
    begin
    Start:
    clrscr;
    writeln('write text (from ',tmin,' to ',tmax,' chars): ');
    readln(t);
    l:=length(t);

    if (l<tmin) or (l>tmax) then
    begin
    writeln('Text doesn't apply to rules!');
    goto end;
    end;
    clrscr;
    begin
    randomize;
    repeat
    x:=random(52+1);
    y:=random(80+1);
    textcolor(white);

    gotoxy(x,y);
    writeln(t);

    delay(700);
    clrscr;
    until keypressed;
    end;
    ord (readkey)<>27 then
    goto Start;
    end:
    end.
```

Comment: You should fix the formatting of the code. Also, the code above will not even compile. Finally, I don't see the relation between the actual question and the code.

Comment: You should simply use the `Trim` function to remove the spaces.

Comment: I compiled the code and it works and I cant use trim function its a school work and teacher asked us to use while do function.

Comment: No, the code above will certainly not compile. Anyhow, have you tried to solve the problem using only a `while` loop?

Comment: The code is that what I got so far next thing is when I write that text before checking its length I need to remove spaces from beginning and end of it

Comment: How will it help you if we do your homework? Serious question. What's the answer?

Comment: Please don't claim you compiled this code. At least two syntax errors: `end:` and the single quote in the middle of `'Text doesn't apply to rules!'` which makes it a syntactically incorrect string. There are problems here as well: `const tmin=1; tmax=30;
    label
    Start,
    end;` If you want to be successful at programming, you need to be concerned about every detail.

Answer (score 5):

**Academic problem:** Remove leading and trailing spaces from a string using a `while` loop.

How do we approach this problem?

Well, we certainly would like to create a *function* that trims a string. This way, we can simply call this function every time we need to perform such an operation. This will make the code much more readable and easier to maintain.

Clearly, this function accepts a string and returns a string. Hence its declaration should be

```
function Trim(const AText: string): string;
```

Here I follow the convention of prefixing arguments by "A". I also use the `const` prefix to tell the compiler I will not need to modify the argument within the function; this can improve performance (albeit very slightly).

The definition will look like this:

```
function Trim(const AText: string): string;
begin
  // Compute the trimmed string and save it in the result variable.
end;
```

## A first attempt

Now, let's attempt to implement this algorithm using a `while` loop. Our first attempt will be very slow, but fairly easy to follow.

First, let us copy the argument string `AText` to the `result` variable; when the function returns, the value of `result` will be its returned value:

```
result := AText;
```

Now, let us try to remove *leading* space characters.

```
while result[1] = ' ' do
  Delete(result, 1, 1);
```

We test if the first character, `result[1]`, is a space character and if it is, we use the `Delete` procedure to remove it from the string (specifically, `Delete(result, 1, 1)` removes `1` character from the string starting at the character with index `1`). Then we do this again and again, until the first character is something other than a space.

For example, if `result` initially is `'     Hello, World!'`, this will make it equal to `'Hello, World!'`.

Full code, so far:

```
function Trim(const AText: string): string;
begin
  result := AText;
  while result[1] = ' ' do
    Delete(result, 1, 1);
end;
```

Now try this with a string that consists only of space characters, such as `'     '`, or the empty string, `''`. What happens? Why?

*Think about it.*

Clearly, in such a case, `result` will sooner or later be the empty string, and then the character `result[1]` doesn't exist. (Indeed, if the first character of `result` would exist, `result` would be of length at least 1, and so it wouldn't be the empty string, which consists of precisely zero characters.)

*Accessing a character that doesn't exist will make the program crash.*

To fix this bug, we change the loop to this:

```
while (Length(result) >= 1) and (result[1] = ' ') do
  Delete(result, 1, 1);
```

Due to a technique known as 'lazy boolean evaluation' (or ['short-circuit evaluation'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)), the second operand of the `and` operator, that is, `result[1] = ' '`, will not even run if the first operand, in this case `Length(result) >= 1`, evaluates to `false`. Indeed, `false and <anything>` equals `false`, so we already know the value of the conjunction in this case.

In other words, `result[1] = ' '` will only be evaluated if `Length(result) >= 1`, in which case there will be no bug. In addition, the algorithm produces the right answer, because if we eventually find that `Length(result) = 0`, clearly we are done and should return the empty string.

Removing *trailing* spaces in a similar fashion, we end up with

```
function Trim(const AText: string): string;
begin
  result := AText;

  while (Length(result) >= 1) and (result[1] = ' ') do
    Delete(result, 1, 1);

  while (Length(result) >= 1) and (result[Length(result)] = ' ') do
    Delete(result, Length(result), 1);
end;
```

### A tiny improvement

I don't quite like the space character literals `' '`, because it is somewhat difficult to tell visually how many spaces there are. Indeed, we might even have a different whitespace character than a simple space. Hence, I would write `#32` or `#$20` instead. `32` (decimal), or `$20` (hexadecimal), is the character code of a normal whitespace.

### A (much) better solution

If you try to trim a string containing many million of characters (including a few million leading and trailing spaces) using the above algorithm, you'll notice that it is surprisingly slow. This is because we in every iteration need to reallocate memory for the string.

A much better algorithm would simply determine the number of leading and trailing spaces by reading characters in the string, and then in a single step perform a memory allocation for the new string.

In the following code, I determine the index `FirstPos` of the first non-space character in the string and the index `LastPos` of the last non-space character in the string:

```
function Trim2(const AText: string): string;
var
  FirstPos, LastPos: integer;
begin

  FirstPos := 1;
  while (FirstPos <= Length(AText)) and (AText[FirstPos] = #32) do
    Inc(FirstPos);

  LastPos := Length(AText);
  while (LastPos >= 1) and (AText[LastPos] = #32) do
    Dec(LastPos);

  result := Copy(AText, FirstPos, LastPos - FirstPos + 1);

end;
```

I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader to figure out the precise workings of the algorithm. As a bonus exercise, try to benchmark the two algorithms: how much faster is the last one? (Hint: we are talking about orders of magnitude!)

### A simple benchmark

For the sake of completeness, I wrote the following very simple test:

```
const
  N = 10000;
var
  t: cardinal;
  dur1, dur2: cardinal;
  S: array[1..N] of string;
  S1: array[1..N] of string;
  S2: array[1..N] of string;
  i: Integer;
begin

  Randomize;

  for i := 1 to N do
    S[i] := StringOfChar(#32, Random(10000)) + StringOfChar('a', Random(10000)) + StringOfChar(#32, Random(10000));

  t := GetTickCount;
  for i := 1 to N do
    S1[i] := Trim(S[i]);
  dur1 := GetTickCount - t;

  t := GetTickCount;
  for i := 1 to N do
    S2[i] := Trim2(S[i]);
  dur2 := GetTickCount - t;

  Writeln('trim1: ', dur1, ' ms');
  Writeln('trim2: ', dur2, ' ms');

end.
```

I got the following output:

```
trim1: 159573 ms
trim2: 484 ms
```

Comment: Maybe strutils.removeleadingchars(s,[' ']);   Procedural form doesn't reallocate., but this is a set version which is slower I guess.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort: The above answer is for educational purposes only, given the nature of the question. In real life, one would of course use the RTL's `Trim` function.

Comment: Just thought it would be fun to have all three metrics.